# FormView not providing OldValues to its SqlDataSource on Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource, formview

I have been searching for this solution for 4 days -- help me stackoverflow.. you're my only hope.

I'm using a FormView to enable editing the rows of a large table.  The FormView's DataSource is specified using the DataSourceId attribute.

The SqlDataSource has OldValuesParameterFormatString specified, as well as the ConflictDetection set as "CompareAllValues".

My problem is that the OldValues haven't been set by the FormView so the CompareAllValues can't happen during an Update command.

I've scoured the Internets and have come across suggestions but none of them have solved the problem.  I'm hoping someone knows why the OldValues aren't being set.

Here's the (simplified) code:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormViewPlanAgain" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlPlanSourceAgain"     DataKeyNames="PlansRID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("PlanName") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxTextBox id="ASPxTextBox36" runat="server" CssClass="floatLeft veryLarge" Text='<%# Bind("PlanName") %>' />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="Server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="Server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlPlanSourceAgain" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cpaConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="Select * FROM Plans WHERE Plans.PlansRID = @PlansRID" SelectCommandType="Text"
            UpdateCommand="Plans_Update" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" OnSelecting="SqlPlanSource_Selecting">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="PlansRID" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="GroupsRID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ProductCodeRID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ProductRID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PoolRID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PlanName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PlanID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="AdminPercent" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ArizonaEmployees" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="BenefitChanges" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="EmployeesAfterWaivers" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ParticipationPercent" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="TheoreticalPremium" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CCBrokerOnCorrespondence" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ClaimSystemPlanNameRider" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="COBRAAdminEntityRID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Commission" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CoveragePastRetirement" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DependentAgeLimit" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DomesticPartnerCoverage" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="EligibleEmployeeCount" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="EmployerGroupContribution" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="EnrollmentCount" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ERISA" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ExternalID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ExternalCarrierEntityRID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FundingTypeRID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GenerateRenewal" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="HandbookTypeRID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="HandbookDistributionRID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="InternalCOB" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LegalGuardianship" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="NewHireWaitingPeriod" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="OnlineEnrollment" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ParticipationRequirement" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RiskPercent" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RiskTier" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SASDivisionRID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SASPlanRID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContractLengthRID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="StepChildrenCoverageTypeRID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="TargetLossRatio" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="UnderwritingCompanyRID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="VoluntaryContributoryTypeRID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="EditorUsersRID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="EffectiveStartDate" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="EffectiveEndDate" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Stamp" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SequenceNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ActiveFlag" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Note" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="HistoryNotes" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

To be clear, I cut out all the other fields in the ItemTemplate and EditItemTemplate, to save you a headache.  I left them in the SqlDataSource so you can see that it's quite a few fields I'm playing with.

As far as I know, I've set everything up correctly, even completely redoing everything from scratch, just to make sure.  Does anyone have any tips in mind?  Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the original values to your parameter list:

```
<UpdateParameters> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="GroupsRID" Type="Int32" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_GroupsRID" Type="Int32" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="ProductCodeRID" Type="Int32" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ProductCodeRID" Type="Int32" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="ProductRID" Type="Int32" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ProductRID" Type="Int32" />
```

You will also need to modify your stored procedure (Plans_Update) to accept these values.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I had tried that before but tried again just in case.  It unfortunately doesn't prevent the error from being thrown down: "You have specified that your update command compares all values on SqlDataSource 'SqlPlanSourceAgain', but the dictionary passed in for oldValues is empty.  Pass in a valid dictionary for update or change your mode to OverwriteChanges." Also, the stored procedure is expecting the original_ values.

Comment: I think the parameters are what will be passed to the stored procedure from the SqlDataSource, but the SqlDataSource hasn't yet been provided the OldValues dictionary by the FormView, so it can't fill in those original_ parameters.

Comment: @iAmWonder - Since you appear to be using 3rd party controls in your FormView, have you tried using <asp:ControlParameter rather than <asp:Parameter so you can map the values to your control values?

Comment: My problem ended up being something else, and I wasn't asking the right question to get that solution.  However, the solution provided is correct, so I'll mark it as such. Cheers!